# La cláusula HAVING no funciona como se esperaba

Tags: mysql, sql

quiero proyectar el código y cantidad de inscritos de los cursos cuya cantidad de inscritos del curso sea menor al promedio de los inscritos en total,me puse a investigar y debo utilizar un `having` pero sigue sin funcionar,adjunto mi código sql, es bien sencillo,yo soy nuevo en esto, les pido paciencia,gracias por su tiempo.

```
select codigo,cant_inscriptos
from cursos 
HAVING cant_inscriptos < AVG(cant_inscriptos);
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la llave primaria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El uso de la clausula **`HAVING`** espera trabajar con columnas que fueron calculadas por ejemplo con las funciones de agregación como:

- **`SUM`**
- **`COUNT`**
- **`AVG`**
- etc.

Entonces lo primero sería modificar esa condición de esta forma:

- Pasa a la columna `cant_inscriptos` por la función `COUNT`eso te devolverá un conteo de los inscritos por curso dale un alias al cálculo resultante para que lo recuperes después
- Posterior tenecitarás agrupar, eso lo haces por la columna `codigo`
- Al final ya puedes establecer tu condición para filtrar por medio de `HAVING`

**PROPUESTA DE CONSULTA**

```
select codigo, COUNT(cant_inscriptos) AS Total
from cursos 
group by codigo
HAVING Total < AVG(cant_inscriptos);
```

Se anexa el siguiente link con documentación oficial acerca de la cláusula `HAVING`:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -1):

La funcion `HAVING` requiere la funcion de agregacion `count(1)`